# MailKit HtmlBody Always Null

Tags: mailkit

I"m trying to get the html from an email retrieved in Gmail. No issues getting the emails however when I attempt to get the HtmlBody it is always null. HTML is present according to the bodyparts.

```
     using (var imap = new ImapClient())
     {
          imap.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993);
          imap.Authenticate(Login, PW);
          var inbox = imap.Inbox;
          inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

          string body = "";
          if (html)
               {
                    body = inbox.GetMessage(messageID).HtmlBody;
                } else
                {
                    body = inbox.GetMessage(messageID).TextBody;
                }
                
                imap.Disconnect(true);

                return body;
            }
```

I can see from the bodyparts that html is present and if I use this linq I'm able to get the encoded html.

```
 var msg = inbox.GetMessage(messageID).BodyParts.OfType<MimePart>().First(x => x.ContentType.MimeType == "text/html");
```

[image]

Using this I can see there is a Text property but I'm not able to retrieve it. Can anyone assist in getting the unmodified html from Mailkit?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your LINQ statement to:

```
var msg = inbox.GetMessage(messageID).BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().First(x => x.ContentType.MimeType == "text/html");
```

... you'll be able to access the `.Text` property.

The other option is to cast the `msg` variable to a `TextPart`.

The reason you can't access the `.Text` property in your current code is that this property only exists on the `TextPart` subclass of `MimePart` (which is more abstract).

Comment: Isn't it better to get all `BodyParts` with the mimeType of `text/html`? something like `var text = string.Join("<br>", message.Message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().Where(x => x.ContentType.MimeType == "text/html").Select(x => x.Text).ToArray());`

Comment: No, that would not make sense to do in general because most clients will limit the message body to a single text/html mime-part, so concatenating all text/html parts would end up including html attachments which would *definitely* not be what you want.

Comment: I had an email which was a reply to another email, and the original email was quoted. Your solution did not catch the quoted part for some reason. So, I had to get all `text/html` body parts. The email also had an attachment but `MimeType` was not `text/html`, so I was fine.

Comment: Then maybe whatever client you are dealing with uses a non-standard approach to constructing email. And by non-standard, I don't mean that they are necessarily breaking IETF standards, I just mean that they are not constructing the MIME message in a way that follows the conventions that most clients use.

Comment: The client is GMail.

Comment: Then you are going to have to show me an actual example because I've been using GMail for decades and MimeKit/MailKit works just fine with all of my emails on GMail.